# perform segue with UITableview inside a tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

For reference:

TABLEVIEW (1 section - 3 rows)
in each row I have a custom cell that contains another tableview.

the tableview inside  the custom cell is subclassed with a uitableviewcell
where I implement all of my delegates, like cellforrow etc. etc., and the file owner of the table view inside the `UITableView` cell is with my `UIViewController`.

How can I perform segue using the subclass `UITableViewCell`?

Any ideas what to do?

NOTE: I am using the tableview on the `UITableViewCell` as subclass.

Comment: Typically, segue is used to implement transition between two view controllers. Did you put all the stuffs in the same view controller?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>control</kbd> drag From View Controller to View Controller

[image: From View Controller to View Controlle!]

You will need to give an identifier to your segue:

[image]

Perform the segue:

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                            didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:sender];
 }
```

Now here is the thing, this will just perform the segue, if you ever needed to pass some data to that view controller. Then you have to implement the following segue deleguate:

**prepareForSegue**

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegue"])
    {  
       //pass data here
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me.
already tried this.
Screenshot: http://i1262.photobucket.com/albums/ii615/jorelkimcruz/ScreenShot2014-04-25at124607PM_zps24e29260.png

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<movieDetailViewController: 0x98761c0>) has no segue with identifier 'moviedetail''


but already set my segue identifier on the storyboard

Comment: @FanBoy-designAnd-concept I expanded on my answer

Comment: this dont work for UITableViewCell type of  class, fixed my problem by   redoing the task. instead of using the UITableViewCell as a sublcass of a UITableView. i programmatically made the tableViews to the viewcontrollers. because UITableViewCell doesnt recognize the segues. AFAIK. anyways thanks for the answer.