# Unwind Segue with UITableView Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, unwind-segue

I have referred to both of these and others on this issue and wasn't able to resolve my problem following their steps. I don't have enough "points" to comment on them so I'm asking my question here.

using unwindToSegue on a `UIButton` works, but not on a `UITableViewCell`

I have my `unwindToSegue()` function in my MainView controller, and I have a SubViewController that has a view and a table inside of it's view.

I've tried control dragging from Cell to exit and using both the Selection Segue and Accessory Segue.

[perform segue with UITableview inside a tableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283384/perform-segue-with-uitableview-inside-a-tableviewcell)

[Unwind Segue with UITableViewCell in Xamarin.iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450111/unwind-segue-with-uitableviewcell-in-xamarin-ios)

Link to this test project
https://github.com/zgmorris13/swiftMenuSystem

Comment: Maybe you need to give a link of the demo.

Comment: NSDeveloper I have added a link to the git repository with this test project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "scriptureCell")
```

Just remove this.Everything is OK. These explain why:

[tableviewdequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-issues-with-global-constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463023/tableviewdequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-issues-with-global-constant)

matt's answer to [uitableview-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022763/uitableview-in-swift)

James Wang's answer to 
[Assertion failure in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath)

Comment: This was exactly it. thanks! Now I need someone who can give me 5 hours of my life back.